# VS 2012 ultimate - can't find "Store" menu

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, menuitem

I'm using VS2012 ultimate for developing windows phone 8 apps. I want to run the "Create app package" wizard which is located under Store menu item but I can't find that Store item neither under Project nor as a standalone menu item.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

By default the Store item is under the Project menu.
But you cannot submit a Windows Phone 8.0 app from Visual Studio.

You must perform a build using a Release configuration, and you will find the XAP file under the Bin/Release directory.

You can then submit the XAP to the Windows Phone dev center (http://dev.windowsphone.com)

Comment: thank you for your reply. according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh975357.aspx), I must go through this wizard in order to generate this file. Anyway, I've searched in my Release folder and found the xap file but the upload didn't work.  it keeps saying: "2004: Something's happened, and we're not quite sure what. We haven't lost any of your app's info, so try resubmitting again. If you continue to see this message, try submitting your app at a later time.". Any help pleaseee